# how to install gnome2 on lubuntu11.10

Tags: 11.10, lubuntu, lxde, gnome2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Now i am running lubuntu11.10, which is based on lxde, i want to install gnome2 on lubuntu, iow, i want to have both gnome2 and lxde on it. i googled for some time. and i got some commands such as `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, `sudo apt-get install gnome-core` etc. i tried the first one `ubuntu-desktop`, but when i finished installing it, i found it was desktop based on gnome3! now i have uninstalled it. can anyone tell me how to install gnome2 on lubuntu11.10? thx a million!

Comment: ... I'm closing this since its identical to other similar gnome-2 questions for ubuntu 11.10 and its official variants.

Answer (score 0):

The Gnome2-project is dead. So there are no packages in the offical PPAs. The best you could do is install the fork Mate or Cinnamon, where I prefere Cinnamon.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```